# Prove $\frac{S_{n}}{n} \overset{p}{\rightarrow} p$ where $S_n$ is a binomial random variable.

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, binomial-distribution

I want to prove that $\frac{1}{n}S_{n} \overset{p}{\longrightarrow} p\:$ as $\:n \longrightarrow \infty$ from first principles,

where $S_{n}$ denotes the number of successes in $n$ binomial trials with success probability $p$.

From the definition of convergence in probability.

A random sequence $Y_{n}$ converges in probability to $c$ if:

$$P(|Y_{n} - c| < \epsilon) \longrightarrow 1\text{ as } n \longrightarrow \infty$$

For every $\epsilon > 0$.

We can do the following:

$$\begin{align}P\left(\left|\frac{S_{n}}{n} - p\right| < \epsilon\right) &= P\left(\frac{S_{n}}{n} - p < \epsilon\right) - P\left(\frac{S_{n}}{n} - p < -\epsilon\right) \\&= P(S_{n} < n(p + \epsilon)) - P(S_{n} < n(p - \epsilon))\end{align}$$

I assume that the result follows the binomial cdf. But im not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This is the weak law of large numbers.  The binomial cdf is not pretty and probably not a helpful approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P(|\frac {S_n} n-p|>\epsilon) \leq \frac {E(\frac {S_n} n-p)^{2}} {\epsilon^{2}}$.

$E(\frac {S_n} n-p)^{2}=\frac  1 {n^{2}} E( \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i-p))^{2}$. Expand the square and note that $E(X_i-p)(X_j-p)=0$ for $i \neq j$. Compute $E(X_i-p)^{2}$ and finally note that $\frac {p(1-p)} n\epsilon^{2} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$.

Comment: I want to prove it from first principles.

Comment: @DanielDeWet This is a proof from first principles. I think you mean to say that you want a proof by analyzing the binomial cdf.

Comment: Is it at all possible to prove  using the binomial cdf?